# Plotting the graph for exp(cos(1/x))

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am having issues plotting the function `exp(cos(1/x))` in the domain (0,1) with pgfplots and TikZ using a normal `addplot` command with the function `exp(cos(deg(1/x)))`. It seems LaTeX is having some trouble with the precision of some very small numbers - this is my current output:

[image]

The function should have maxima and minima at `exp(1)` and `exp(-1)` but some of those aren't getting all the way up to those extrema. Do you have suggestions how to improve the result?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-0.01, xmax=1.05, ymin=-0.01, ymax=2.85, y=1cm/0.25, x=1cm/0.1,
            grid=both,
            domain=0:1,
            restrict y to domain=0:3,
            xtick={1},
            ytick={0.36,2.7182},
            yticklabels={$\exp(-1)$, $\exp(1)$},
            samples=1000,
            axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}]
            \addplot[domain=0.00001:1, blue] {exp(cos(deg(1/x)))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please show the sample code you use to generate that figure? Thank you!

Comment: No software can draw the graph in the vicinity of 0.

Comment: Please provide complete code i.e. something we can compile rather than requiring people to guess how to complete it.

Comment: @darthbith Please refer to my edited MWE.

Comment: @cfr Please refer to my edited MWE.

Comment: I tried with Grapher on Mac OS X; the behavior is very similar, except that it chokes a bit nearer to 0, because the software can use better accuracy. See [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tUo3i.png). It simply impossible for *any* software to be accurate in the vicinity of 0.

Comment: @egreg This should be a sketch and doesn't have to be an accurate plot - I guess my best solution is to pick a smaller range like (0.01, 0.2) s.t. I get a better result?

Comment: Try increasing `samples=1000` to something like `samples=10000` or `50000` or even larger. This takes more time to compile, but seems to have better results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX has insufficient math capabilities for drawing this graph with sufficient accuracy; *no* software can draw it near zero, of course.

With `gnuplot`, restricting the domain to a more sensible interval and increasing the number of samples, I get a good drawing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-0.05, xmax=1.05, ymin=-0.01, ymax=2.85, y=1cm/0.25, x=1cm/0.1,
  grid=both,
  domain=0.05:1,
  restrict y to domain=0:3,
  xtick={1},
  ytick={0.36,2.7182},
  yticklabels={$\exp(-1)$, $\exp(1)$},
  samples=1000,
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}]
  \addplot[domain=0.03:1, blue,samples=10000] gnuplot {exp(cos(1/x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that `gnuplot` uses radians by default. You should enable `-shell-escape` for this.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can create a parametric plot, placing samples closer together as x\to 0.
In this case, x=1, 10/11, 10/12, ..., 0.01

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-0.01, xmax=1.05, ymin=-0.01, ymax=2.85, y=1cm/0.25, x=1cm/0.1,
            grid=both,
            xtick={1},
            ytick={0.36,2.7182},
            yticklabels={$\exp(-1)$, $\exp(1)$},
            variable=t,
            samples at={10,...,1000},
            axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}]
            \addplot[blue,smooth] ({10/t},{exp(cos(deg(.1*t)))});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: parametric]

Answer (score 0):

That's called aliasing. Near zero this function has an effective "frequency" (using the term loosely) which is higher than your sampling rate. It's natural then for the samples to miss the interesting features of the curve and end up looking wrong. John Kormylo's suggestion of an adaptive sampling rate is quite good.

Comment: This should be a comment to @John Kormylo's answer, not an answer by itself, IMO.

Comment: Possibly. I debated which way to go but decided the explanation of why it happens should be in an answer, not a comment.