# Parametric irrational system of equations with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I thought of parametric form to the following system of equations,

[image]

but it was difficult for me. Please help me to declare it in a parametric function drawn in `pgfplots`.

Comment: did you square both and add ? or add and square? This is not irrational it's implicit by the way

Comment: These are arcs of parabolas.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280595/plotting-the-graph-for-expcos1-x/280607?s=1|0.4487#280607 for example.

Comment: Did one of the tricks help to solve your problem? At least you could have answered to the comments ...

Comment: O yeah, apologize. Sure, I've posted it here http://menulislatex.blogspot.co.id/2015/12/menggambar-fungsi-implisit.html.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.