# Pgfplots error when graphing trig function when "/" is inside!

Tags: pgfplots, errors, overleaf, graphs, brackets

I'm trying to graph the function, x * tan(pi/x) in Pgfplots, but it always comes up with the errors:

- Argument of \pgfmathfloattoint@@ has an extra }
- Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
- Runaway argument?
- Extra \else
- Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)

If I replace the "/" with any other sign, like *, +, or -, it works... but for any trig function, it won't let me use "/". I've already tried using negative exponents (x^{-1}), but it still doesn't work.

I've tried clearing my cache and still nothing. I'd appreciate some help with this problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,angles,quotes,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows.meta,backgrounds,decorations,pathreplacing}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usetkzobj{all}

\definecolor{antiquewhite}{rgb}{0.98, 0.92, 0.84}
\sethlcolor{antiquewhite}
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}
\newcommand\nbvspace[1][3]{\vspace*{\stretch{#1}}}
\newcommand\nbstretchyspace{\spaceskip0.5em plus 0.25em minus 0.25em}
\newcommand{\nbtitlestretch}{\spaceskip0.6em}
\geometry{
a4paper,
total={216mm,303mm},
left=20mm,
top=20mm,
}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        x=0.5cm,
        y=0.5cm,
        every axis plot/.append style={very thick},
        axis lines=center,
        every axis y label/.style={ 
            at={(ticklabel cs:0.9)},anchor=near yticklabel opposite,fill=white,
        },
        xlabel={$n$},
        ylabel={$f(n)$},
        xmin=0, xmax=30,
        ymin=-5, ymax=15,
        xtick={0,5,10,...,30},
        ytick={-5,0,5,10,15},
        ymajorgrids=true,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        domain = 0:30,
    ]
    
    \addplot[color=black,samples=1000,trig format=rad]{x*tan(pi/x)};
    
    \addplot[color=black,samples=200,style=dashed,]{pi};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%
```

Comment: It seems that the problem is the domain. If you use `0.00001:30` it works, apart from quite a bit of `dimension too large` error  (add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` or whatever version you have). The error is not the best one, I have to say...

Comment: BTW, there are a lot of things that give errors here with your snippet...

Comment: Reported with a minimal example https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1027

Comment: At x=0 the function is not defined. Perhaps the division by zero should be caught with an appropriate message, but it would be an error nontheless.

Comment: I might mention in passing that the default is to use degrees instead of radians.  To convert use deg(pi/x) or (pi/x r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dividing by zero, which is of course not allowed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        x=0.5cm,
        y=0.5cm,
        every axis plot/.append style={very thick},
        axis lines=center,
        every axis y label/.style={ 
            at={(ticklabel cs:0.9)},anchor=near yticklabel opposite,fill=white,
        },
        xlabel={$n$},
        ylabel={$f(n)$},
        xmin=0, xmax=30,
        ymin=-5, ymax=15,
        xtick={0,5,10,...,30},
        ytick={-5,0,5,10,15},
        ymajorgrids=true,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        domain = 0:30,
    ]
    
    \addplot[color=black,samples=1000,trig format=rad]{x*tan(pi/ifthenelse(x,x,1))};
    
    \addplot[color=black,samples=200,style=dashed,]{pi};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Instead of dividing by *x*, I divide by `ifthen(x,x,1)`, so if *x* is zero, one is returned.

[image]

On the other hand, the graph is bound to be very rough, because the function has infinitely many asymptotes in the interval (0,2) although apparently none is caught with the given sample rate.

By the way, the function has no limit at 0.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the solution worked. I'm facing an issue where if I "zoom" into the graph by decreasing y-min and y-max to 3.1 and 3.2, respectively, I get these jagged-looking lines, when the graph should be smooth. Increasing sample size makes the weird effect worse. Is this just a limitation of PGF? Or is there another method to solve this problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @MacmillanSmith The graph *cannot* be smooth in the interval (0,2), because there are infinitely many asymptotes accumulating near 0. No rendering software can cope with this.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280595/plotting-the-graph-for-expcos1-x

Comment: I get the (0,2) interval, but if I go to any interval, like (500,1000), it's still very jagged and not smooth.